# split() not working if the string to be splitted is coming from a text file

Tags: javascript, split, readfile

//I can split a string in the following way without problem

```
var string1 = "abc def ghi";
var res = string1.split(" ");
var split1 = res[1]; // abc
var split2 = res[2]; // def
var split3 = res[3]; // ghi
```

//But my string that has to be split is coming from reading a textfile (text)
//Unfortunately this is not working

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("./mytext.txt", function(text){
var textByLine = text.split("\n")
});

var res = text.split(" ");
var split1 = res[1]; 
var split2 = res[2]; 
var split3 = res[3];
```

Comment: is this java or javascript code? (tag says java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is Javascript and not Java code, the problem is that you're trying to access the `text` variable outside of the callback function. The value from the `readFile` will only be available inside of its callback function.

You should use `fs.readFileSync` to get the value directly and work with it. See [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) for more details on using the function, but this should work:

```js
var fs = require("fs")
var text = fs.readFileSync("./mytext.txt")
var textByLine = text.split("\n")

console.log("first line:",textByLine[0])
```